# Excel VBA - Grouping list of strings in one cell

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know how to best describe this but it's better that I explain my problem in pictures.

I have 2 worksheets:

In worksheet *Array,* there are certain periods with their corresponding 'Array' associated with them.

[image: Worksheet Array]

In *Sheet1*,  there is a list of strings in the format: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM - # ordered by ascending order of number, then by date and finally by time.

[image: Sheet1]

The code I have, generates those values in *Sheet1* by extracting the data in *Array* and listing them out in one cell. The code I've used is.

```
Sub Filter()
Const Array_FirstRow As Integer = 2 'Indicates the first row (row 2) in Array sheet
Dim Array_RowIndex As Integer 'variable to loop through array values of col A

Dim Summary_PeriodMoment1 As String 'in worksheet Sheet 1
Array_RowIndex = Array_FirstRow
Array_LastRow = Array_RowIndex - 1
Summary_PeriodMoment1 = ""

For Array_RowIndex = Array_FirstRow To Array_LastRow
  If Summary_PeriodMoment1 <> " " Then
  Summary_PeriodMoment1 = Summary_PeriodMoment1 & ", " & Worksheets("Array").Cells(Array_RowIndex, Array_DateTime_Column).Value
  End If
Next
Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = Summary_PeriodMoment1
End Sub
```

This is slightly confusing and overly complicated to read. Is there any way to add code to :

1. Sort/group the values by # and consolidate by date (to make it less confusing)? Like so?

[image: Sorted/Grouped by #]

2. Have a separate cell for each value, again categorized by # (I would like to plot these values on a pivot graph later on using other code, so would like it to be in a friendly format

[image: desirable output]

Essentially I would like to do some data reformatting/transposing with a VBA script. Any idea what functions I should use? thanks!

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Update: I have what I need for transposing a  string of values in **one** cell. I wonder if this can be done for multiple cells. I tried using this code:

```
 Sub TextToRows()
'Code for 1.2. section
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim Arr1 As Variant
Dim Arr2 As Variant
Dim InputRng As Range, InputRng2 As Range, InputRng3 As Range, OutputRng As Range, OutputRng1 As Range, OutputRng2 As Range

Set InputRng = Range("B1") 'Cell Containing all the text
Set InputRng1 = Range("B2")
Set InputRng2 = Range("B3")
Set OutputRng = Range("D1") 'First Cell of a column that you want the output there
Set OutputRng1 = Range("G1")
Set OutputRng2 = Range("J1")

Arr = Split(InputRng.Value, ",")
Arr1 = Split(InputRng.Value, ",")
Arr2 = Split(InputRng.Value, ",")

Set OutputRng = OutputRng.Resize(UBound(Arr) - LBound(Arr) + 1)
OutputRng.Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)

Set OutputRng1 = OutputRng1.Resize(UBound(Arr1) - LBound(Arr1) + 1)
OutputRng.Value = Application.Transpose(Arr1)

Set OutputRng2 = OutputRng2.Resize(UBound(Arr2) - LBound(Arr2) + 1)
OutputRng.Value = Application.Transpose(Arr2)

End Sub
```

Seems it only works for InputRng and not InputRng1 or InputRng2
[image]

Comment: Transposing is one way, can you not modify the code that generates the data to be more friendly?

Comment: How many records you got in the B1? More than 16000?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, can you copy/paste a sample of the data to the post, so we can more easily re-create your issue and work on it on our end?

Comment: Yes there is a way to add the code.  You can use the Split function, and then do some sorting to get things in the correct order.  To have it all sorted into a single cell, one way would be to create a User Defined Object of the `#` with all of the applicable times, and then recreate the display however you want.

Comment: Implement the first part and then play around with the second part of your question and show us some code. So we may be able to help you reach your goal.

Comment: @Masoud I've added code! Also, yes it would be less than 16000. Why do you ask about this specific number? Anything I should pay attention to?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I'm not sure what's meant by user defined object, would you care to elaborate. Could I have each #-date/time combination in different cells?

Comment: @BruceWayne Hello, please note i've added code above, hope it's clear. Personally I don't think the code is as important

Comment: @NickSlash I just mentioned transposing for the sake of it. I don't actually know what specific commands can be used for transposing. would you have an idea?

Comment: That number is the limit of the columns in excels. You can use built in text to column, delimiter "," , in Data tab and then transpose them. Again use that, this time on the transposed data, with delimiter " : ". Then there are numerous posts about how to group data into columns based on one column.

Comment: @Urvil You can start by reading Chip Pearsons [Introduction to Classes](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
How to split comma-delimited data in one cell? *(Look below)*

1.1. If you don't have any other data, and number of records are not more than number of possible columns in excel then transposing within the worksheet is an option (Instead of using the code below).

1.2. (If you have more data than limit of excel columns): Otherwise, you need to use arrays. The code below answers first part of your question. It will split the cell for *","* as delimiter.

2.
Then you can use *Text to Columns* in *Data* tab and delimiter *":"* to get the numbers in one column and dates in another one.

3.
Use [How To Transpose Cells In One Column Based On Unique Values In Another Column?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3358-excel-transpose-unique-values.html) to group them based on the numbers.

```
Sub TextToRows()
'Code for 1.2. section
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim InputRng As Range, OutputRng As Range

Set InputRng = Range("B1") 'Cell Containing all the text

Set OutputRng = Range("D1") 'First Cell of a column that you want the output there

Arr = Split(InputRng.Value, ",")

Set OutputRng = OutputRng.Resize(UBound(Arr) - LBound(Arr) + 1)
OutputRng.Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, I will try the first part and get back to you.

Comment: @Urvil Updated my answer. Now it solves your problem completely. (Tested on a sample data)

Comment: Hi Masoud, I've tried it and so far it works! My next question is- how can  I get the code to run for multiple values? For example, I have a string of characters in B1, B2 and B2 and want to paste them in cells D1, G1 and H1. I tried manipulating the code, but to no avail (my reply has the updated code).

Comment: @Urvil I'd suggest accepting this answer and posting another question with this code and your specific question about how to update it. You would also refer to this question for the record. Expanding scope of the question is not a good approach on SO as it causes not getting the answer in most cases, not drawing enough attention, etc. And [Why you should accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Masoud. I just saw this message seconds after I posted the update on this same question. Should I create a new question or is it okay this time round?

Comment: @Urvil I suggest posting new question. you just need to cut and paste the updates over there. That would increase your chance to get an answer.